# What to do if I need to support ios4 muititask when build an app?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios, multitasking

I am developing an app, it gets a list of locations from internet, and will trigger map app when click one item of the table list.

I found when I try to go back from map app (double tap or just one tap of the home key), my app just restart to the first screen.

I know ios4 have multitask feature, my app is built with SDK3 and test in my new ipod4. What can I do if I want to user see the last screen that he left when he came back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to build with iOS 4 (NOT 3) and you will automatically have fast switching enabled.

But fast switching only works on iOS 4.

Answer (score 2):

You should set your build SDK to the most current.  You can still support your app for users with older OS's by setting the apps deployment target.  See [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html) for some tips, tricks and common setups.